# Coldfusion, default ORM object?

Tags: orm, coldfusion

so I have a form that I'm using for new items, and to edit items.

The input fields therefore may have a value or not. I'm using this code in the value field.

`<input name="uuid" value="<cfif isNull(item.GetUuid())>#item.GetUuid()#</cfif>"/>`

Is this the best way to do it? I would have thought the ORM returning a blank object or something maybe cleaner, but not sure of a tider way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
<cfproperty name="uuid" default="">
```

Comment: It says "item" is not defined? So doesn't even return object?

Comment: if your uuid is string, which should be, if u can output it directly inside hash hash, then default="" would work.